# Can Chrome auto pick up a username and password from a database using C#

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and I am currently working on a GUI for a database.

The problem I am running into is that I need to find a way to have the GUI log in to a database in chrome automatically using the username and password that they will provide to open the GUI.

Again, I am new to coding and I do not know if this is possible but I can't find a way to have chrome auto enter that information and open a link that will allow user to create a new transaction.

I am using C#.

I tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://database.spinca.com/transaction/new/");
```

But that only gets me to the login page.

Comment: You could create a hash and add it to your database with some credentials of the authenticated user. Then open chrome with another page with this hash via GET, it's safe if only your server know the hash. Use the credentials retrieved from the database after comparison with the hash to log the user in, or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You add your code to the Web Server side. The browser (which hosts/renders the UI) communicates with the Server (which returns the UI code to the browser.)  I suggest taking a quick training class on web based technologies and learn the relationship between Browser and web server.  The browser cannot communicate directly with local resources (such as a database or disk). There are many blogs and books available on this subject - or use Pluralsight.  Khan Academy has an intro to HTML/JS but is strictly Client side (browser) based.

I assume you are using a Microsoft based web server technology (IIS) since you are coding in C#.  There are several hello-world examples, and many are in Visual Studio itself.

If you don't need a Browser (HTML) - you might consider a Windows application.  In that case look into WPF apps which use XAML for UI definition.  Look in Templates Visual C# WPF App in Visual Studio.